# C# Referencing a variable type, name and value in a format string

Tags: c#, string, variables, formatting

I have this problem with some code that generates SQL code, for later passing through a database.
But while I have been working on the code, I thought to myself "There must be a better way to do this"

This is the code i have got so far:

```
if (invoice.ID is string) SQL.AppendFormat($"{nameof(invoice.ID)} = '{invoice.ID}'").Replace(",", ".").Append(", ");
else SQL.AppendFormat($"{nameof(invoice.ID)} = {invoice.ID}").Replace(",", ".").Append(", ");

if (invoice.InvoiceID is string) SQL.AppendFormat($"{nameof(invoice.InvoiceID)} = {invoice.InvoiceID}, ").Replace(",", ".").Append(", "); 
else SQL.AppendFormat($"{nameof(invoice.InvoiceID)} = {invoice.InvoiceID}").Replace(",", ".").Append(", ");

if (invoice.IssuedDate is string) SQL.AppendFormat($"{nameof(invoice.IssuedDate)} = {invoice.IssuedDate}, ").Replace(",", ".").Append(", "); 
else SQL.AppendFormat($"{nameof(invoice.IssuedDate)} = {invoice.IssuedDate}").Replace(",", ".").Append(", ");
```

As you can see I have to reference the variable every time, and I want this code to be as dynamic as possible, as I dont know yet how many columns there is going to be when im done.

So my wish is to be able to copy and paste some code in, and only change one or maybe two variables(preferably one) like this:

```
if ({0} is string) SQL.AppendFormat($"{nameof({0})} = '{{0}}'").Replace(",", ".").Append(", ");
else SQL.AppendFormat($"{nameof({0})} = {{0}}").Replace(",", ".").Append(", ").Format(invoice.ID);
```

I know the above example is not possible, but I hope you can see what I want.

Many thanks in advance, and any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: as a general advisory, this code is **actively dangerous** (it would absolutely allow me to take control of your database server using your UI); it is **very important** to **never** concatenate user input to build SQL queries; you use *parameters*, i.e. `where x.Foo = @foo`, and add a *parameter* to the command object with the matching name and value.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for your input, I will change my code. But I would like to know why this is a dangerous approach? Just so that I can avoid it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: "SQL injection"; search for "Bobby Tables"; or alternatively, consider what happens when I search for invoice `123'; drop table Invoices; --` - or perhaps `123' or 1=1; --` - SQL injection is one of the FIRST ways hackers will try and abuse your systems; there is a range of readily available tooling built specifically to identify and exploit SQL injection vulnerabilities *automatically*, without the attacker needing to understand or do anything by hand

Comment: Okay I looked up "Bobby Tables" and had a good laugh, I see what you mean now, and in the process of looking up you previous comment, I figured out, how to use the SQLCommand parameters which I will use in my code. I believe that in the future I will be more aware of SQL Vulnerabilities and I think a "quick" google search will help me understand the different ways a hacker can use SQL to ruin my day. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from Marc Gravell's comments, you could have something along these lines:

```
    public class SomeInvoiceData
    {
            public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
            public string InvoiceName { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Value
    {
            public static string Formatted(this object o) 
            {
                    if (o is string)
                    {
                            return $"'{o.ToString()}'";
                    }
                    else if(o is DateTime)
                    {
                            return $"'{o.ToString()}'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            return $"{o.ToString()}";
                    }
            }
    }


    public class SQLBuilder
    {
            private List<string> List = new List<string>();
            private string Delimiter = ",";
            public void AppendAll(object instance)
            {
                    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] listProperty = instance.GetType().GetProperties();
                    foreach (var property in listProperty)
                    {
                            var pvalue = property.GetValue(instance);
                            var statement = $"{property.Name} = {pvalue.Formatted()}";
                            List.Add(statement);
                    }
            }
            public string Get()
            {
                    return String.Join(Delimiter, List);
            }
    }
```

result is 
InvoiceID = 123,InvoiceDate = '2/17/2020 10:23:04 AM',InvoiceName = 'invoice for $3.3'

Comment: As this is what I asked for I have marked it as the solution. I did not use this, as my program is going in a production enviroment, and needs to be secure :/. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @sbch1234 - depending what is your underplaying datasource, you could reuse the above code if you, for example, need to build collection of SqlParameter